# How to combine datasets of different sizes

Tags: r

I want to combine datasets of different sizes. I looked up similar posts and some of them suggested using rbindlist, smartbind. There were also some codes using base r but since I'm still in my starting phases, I just used the inbuilt functions.

```
survey1 = read.xlsx(file.choose())
survey2 = read.xlsx(file.choose())
survey = smartbind(survey1,survey2)
```

This worked for me and the datasets were combined appropriately. However upon using 
head(survey) I got the following result.

```
2011.School.Survey.for.Community.Schools.Please.refer.to.the.Data.Dictionary.file.for.more.detailed.information.about.the.format.of.this.data.
     X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18
     X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30 X31 X32 X33
     X34 X35 X36 X37 X38 X39 X40 X41 X42 X43 X44 X45 X46 X47 X48
     X49 X50 ... X1937
     2011.School.Survey.for.District.75.Schools.Please.refer.to.the.Data.Dictionary.file.for.more.detailed.information.about.the.format.of.this.data
```

I expected to see the first five values of the combined dataset. The result is all the column names. Its hard for me to explain more clearly so I have included an image too.

[image: image here]

Comment: What are "inbuilt functions"?

Comment: what is `class(survey)` ?

Comment: Do `head(survey1)` and `head(survey2)` give what you expect? Do `dim(survey1)` and `dim(survey2)` give the same numbers of columns?

Comment: You have lots of columns and the output might be just truncated, try `head(survey[, 1:10])`. You also could change display options for the session, e.g. `options(max.print=5000)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be good if you edited your question. To convey the essence of your question to a reader it is unnecessary to repeat the names of close-on 2000 variables. You could either just put an ellipsis in to show the omitted names, or you could use a simple example to illustrate the problem. As it stands, the bulk of the text in your question is basically wasted ink ... what Tufte would have called "chart junk" in the context of a graphic. Best to remove it.

Comment: @tom class(survey) is data.frame

Comment: @Henry  dim(survey1) --- 1647 1937,     dim(survey2) ---- 57 1768. head(survey1) and head(survey2) give me similar issues.

Comment: @jay.sf I think you are right. head(survey[, 1:10]) does give the results but it is not displayed properly. There is a lot of trailing white space in the first column as the column name is long. Is that the reason that it is not being displayed properly?

Answer (score 0):

You column names don't look very   I would suggest reloading each sheet as follows:

```
survey1 = read.xlsx(file.choose(), startRow = 2)
survey2 = read.xlsx(file.choose(), startRow = 2)
```